# Every element in a free group is conjugate to a cyclically reduced word

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, free-groups, combinatorial-group-theory

Given a free group $F$ generated by a set $X$, which by definition is the set of reduced words in $X \cup X^{-1}$, with reduced concatenation of words, I've come across a statement that says every element in a free group is conjugate to a cyclically reduced word, i.e. $\forall g \in F$, $g=k^{-1}hk$ for some $k\in F$ and some cyclically reduced word $h$.

A word $a_1 \cdots a_l$ is cyclically reduced if it is reduced and either $l=0$ or $a_1 \neq a_l^{-1}$.

I cannot come up with a proof of this statement. I would greatly appreciate it if anyone could help me understand this.

Comment: If I recall correctly, you can find a proof in Magnus *et al*.'s [Combinatorial Group Theory: Presentations of Groups in Terms of Generators and Relations (Dover Books on Mathematics)](https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/0486438309/ref=cm_sw_r_awdo_navT_g_JEBC477679YZ97E55XP5).

Comment: Where did you find the statement?

Comment: Given a reduced word that isn't cyclically reduced, it has the form $a^{-1}wa$ for some $a\in X\cup X^{-1}$ and some reduced word $w$. Conjugate it by $a$ to get the shorter reduced word $w$.  If that's still not cyclically reduced, repeat the same method. At each step, as long as you don't have a cyclically reduced word, the next word will be shorter. And it can't keep getting shorter forever.

Answer (score 1):

If the (reduced) word $w$is cyclically reduced, then there is nothing to prove. If not the first letter of $w$ is the inverse of the last letter: $w=x^{-1}w'x$ where $w'$ is shorter than $w$. Since $w$ is a conjugate of $w'$, we can proceed by induction (a conjugate of a conjugate is a conjugate).